# scala.io.StdIn.readLine pausing execution forever, even after hitting enter in Actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm using readLine within an Akka Actor to allow me to enter some data when some conditions fail. I tested readLine in the REPL and it works as desired. However when i put it into my Actor and readLine is executed the expected thing happens in the console, but when I press enter after entering text in StdIn, nothing happens, it just hangs forever.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the Actor is queuing up a bunch of messages quickly to be processed; this issue is making me think maybe pausing execution in an Actor is a no-no?

Comment: Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, please? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have the same problem with scala.ioStdIn.getLines. For me it always hangs after the last line is processed. I don't think it is an issue with Akka as I'm not using Akka in my case

Comment: in my case it was a very small CSV (3 rows, 3 columns). Its not a sizing issue

Answer (score 0):

in my case my situation was related to the Eclipse IDE's stdIn integration. Even if you configure it to read stdin from a file, it will still attach it to the console so that once the file has been read, you have to still send the termination command from the console for the readlines to complete. 
If you are using a Mac be sure to read the additional quirks with sending the termination command.

[Eclipse reading StdIn(System.in) from console, but will not give any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066724/eclipse-reading-stdinsystem-in-from-console-but-will-not-give-any-output)