# Eclipse reading StdIn(System.in) from console, but will not give any output

Tags: java, eclipse, stdin

My problem is that Eclipse's console is taking input in the console, but it never stops taking input and will not give me any output. I created a method called histogram() that takes an integer M and an array a of integers as input. My code to read input and produce output looks like

```
    int M = StdIn.readInt();
    int[] a = StdIn.readAllInts();
    int[] mossah = histogram(M, a);
    for (int z = 0; z < M; z++) {
    StdOut.printf("%d", mossah[z]);
    }
```

I am not allowed to use other libraries, so please do not suggest one. I was thinking that maybe there's some kind of keyboard shortcut that will make the console stop taking input but I'm not sure. I also tried using `StdIn.readInts()`, which gave me an error that it was depreciated, for array a's input, but it also did not work. If I assign values to array a in the code, I get my desired output, so there is nothing wrong with my method, just that code snippet I put for you guys. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using a Mac OS if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on windows hit Ctrl-Z to send the EOF character

Comment: I am using a Mac OS, so do you know the shortcut to send the EOF on Macs?

Comment: Try Ctrl-D or Cmd-D and please let me know if it worked to update the answer

Comment: Neither works, on Eclipse's shortcut help window, it tells Mac users to use ^D which does not work. I might be doing it wrong, because I am literally pressing ^ and D at the same time.

Comment: Ctrl-D works, but I found out Eclipse on Mac OS has a bug where you have to click off the console and click back on it to send the EOF character.